# how many triangles can be formed by connecting points of an n sided shape and m points inside the shape(without intersecting with other lines)

Tags: geometry

i came across this problem recently, it looked like this:

there is an x sided shape, whats the maximum number of z sided shapes you can form with y additional points in the shape(within the shape) by connecting the lines.
conditions:
there is no absolute answer for where the y points are, and the lines cannot intersect with each other.

i tried solving by just drawing but shortly after i came across 2022 sided shapes.....(STRESS)...............

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler's $v-e+r=2$ formula? That's a good place to start, as you've got $v$, and the shapes having $z$ sides lets you get a relation between $e$ and $r$.

Comment: omg thank u :D xxxxxddddd (im in 7th grade sooo i guess im still learning(btw this apeared in a test

Comment: Good. So, can you answer the question now? If you can, I'd encourage you to write it up and post an answer.